# The Maven bundled with IntelliJ is not offering latest version of various libraries

Tags: maven, caching, intellij-idea, repository, version

In IntelliJ 2019.2.2, I am using the Maven 3.6.1 **bundled inside of the IntelliJ** app. I did *not* download/install Maven separately.

When I add various `<dependency>` elements to my POM, I get errors saying the version of my desired library is not found.

For example JUnit Jupiter:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Maven says no such version, yet [clearly there is such a version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter/5.5.2).

If I clear that `5.5.2` value, and press Control+SpaceBar on my Mac, I get a pop-up menu offering me versions `5.5.1` and earlier.

This JUnit case is just one example. I have this problem repeatedly with many such dependencies being out-of-day, with Maven ignorant of the latest versions. Ruins the whole point of Maven, to take away such drudgery.

➥ Is there a way to get Maven within IntelliJ to update its locale cache of repository data so it can learn about the latest versions?

I have no repositories reported in "Settings (Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Repositories".

[image: screenshot of Settings (Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Repositories]

Comment: Please try to update repositoryies in "Settings (Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Repositories"

Comment: @y.bedrov I have no repositories listed in the IntelliJ prefs for Maven. Added screenshot to the Question.

Comment: Please try 2019.3 EAP version: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/. Repositories list issue should be fixed there.

Comment: @y.bedrov If you would make an Answer of your Comment, I would accept it. In the EAP pre-release, there is indeed an local repo appearing in the list for me to update. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Bug: now fixed

Update repositories in "Settings (Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Repositories".

IntelliJ 2019.2 had a bug where that view is empty, as shown in [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrIoZ.png) in the Question. Now fixed for IntelliJ 2019.3 version. Try the [*IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 Early Access Program*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) pre-release.

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles with not found dependencies in maven too, so i did was use this comand on the terminal(you can use the terminal in the IDE too): mvn clean install -U -X , this command will show you a detail debug of your POM archive, so you can fix every error if exists, after that all your dependecies must be installed again. I hope it helps you.

Comment: I am using the Maven bundled with IntelliJ. I never installed Maven separately on my Mac. So there is no `mvn` command available on the console. I regularly run `clean` & `install` from the Maven panel within IntelliJ, but I believe that has nothing to do with updating the Maven repo cache.